# How to install Teamviewer 11 on Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, xubuntu, teamviewer

I am trying to install Teamviewer on Xubuntu 14.04, the lts version. I have seen so much on this fourm as well as other websites that has not worked. Could somebody please let me know how in DETAILED instructions. 
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps if you can add to your question what instructions you have tried - what error messages etc then we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Download TeamViewer from the [official TeamViewer website](http://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/download/linux/).

Select the [Ubuntu/Debian deb 32-Bit/64-Bit Multiarch version](http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb).

Open the folder where you saved the TeamViewer .deb file and click on it ... that's all.

Software Center opens - click on Install - all dependencies are installed automatically.